# MacPorts-2.0.0 can’t be installed on this computer

Tags: xcode, xcode4, macports, osx-lion

When I try to install macports on Lion I get the following message:

```
MacPorts-2.0.0 can’t be installed on this computer.
Xcode is not installed, or was installed with UNIX Development (10.5+) or Command Line Support (10.4) deselected.
```

Even though I have installed Xcode after upgrading to Lion thru the app store.

Any idea what it is I need to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you get Xcode 4.1 through the App Store, it only downloads the installer for Xcode.  You then need to run the installer.  Look in the system Applications folder for the installer.

Comment: I already have Xcode4 installed via the MacAppStore which I'm using for my iOS development, but I'm getting the same message saying that Xcode is not installed :-(

Comment: Ah. running the Xcode4 installer again and now MacPorts is no longer complaining. I guess it's because I earlier today removed an older installation of MacPorts from my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Xcode with the command line option, which is not default. I had this issue too. Download the Xcode Tools installer, and check the command line option during installation.